# Output difference of two columns excel with exclusion criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet containing all information on machines in our inventory, each machine has a unique ID and a location. Most of the time we have more than 1 machine per site. On occasion, employees visiting sites miss a machine and im looking for a formula that will allow me to compare this week's recorded visits vs the whole collection of machines and output the missing machines *whenever a site has been visited*. Here is an example of the whole system table and the weekly table.

1 - All of the data

2 - This week's visit

3 - Expected output

```
1) Machine No. Location         2)  Machine No. Location     3)  Machine No. Location
    1           a                    1           a               5           b
    2           a                    2           a               11          d
    3           a                    3           a               12          d 
    4           b                    4           b
    5           b                    6           b
    6           b                    10          d
    7           c                    
    8           c                    
    9           c                    
    10          d
    11          d
    12          d
```

So, by the above tables, the output would show; machine 5 (as 2 other machines from Location b have been appeared), machine 11 and machine 12 (as machine 10 from location d has appeared). It would be helpful if the site could be displayed in this 3rd table too.

Note that I do not need to see machines 7,8 or 9 as from the second list, as there is nothing to suggest that location C was visited.

Comment: Thanks for the help dev1998 :)

My machine list happens to be 2k+ fields long. Is there an additional formula or function i can use to push all of the cells in columns J and K that contain a 'hit' to the top of the column? Besides the obvious filter and remove blanks.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this data would be better off in a database, but it's workable in a spreadsheet.

I had the complete machine number list in cells A2 thru A13. The corresponding locations were in B2 thru B13.  I put your visited machines in G2 thru G7, with the visited locations in H2 thru H7.

In cell C2 I put in this: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$H$20,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")`
and then copied it down to C13. That formula looks at the machine in column A and if it is NOT in the visited list it returns "No", otherwise it returns a "Yes".

Then in cell D2 I put this:`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,$H$1:$I$20,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes") and copied it down to D13`
This formula looks at the location in column B and if it was NOT in the visited list it returns "No", otherwise it returns "Yes".

**The machines you are looking for will have a "No" in column C and a "Yes" in column D.**

In J2 I put this:`=IF(C2="Yes","",IF(D2="Yes",A2,""))` and copied it thru J13,
and in K2 I put in this `=IF(C2="Yes","",IF(D2="Yes",B2,""))` and copied it down to K13.

Hopefully this will help you out.

[image: Machines]